# Why User-mode interrupt was introduced in RISC-V?

Tags: interrupt, specifications, riscv

In RISC-V privileged architecture V1.11 or draft of version 1.12, "N" extension is introduced for User-level interrupts, hardware which implemented this extension can transfer control directly to a user-level trap handler without invoking the outer execution environment.

But there are mirrored CSR and instruction for the N extension, for a system which support M and U mode only, the both save and restore similar context for interrupts, **so why the N extension introduced and what benefit can we get?**

Comment: FYI, the N extension has been removed in the ratified V1.12..

Comment: @ErikEidt  Yeap, but I want to know why it was introduced and what benefit can we get if the spec implemented.